# How should I make color-error map like publication?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to make some error map which look like this :

[image]

First time I thought the problem will be solved if I make the hsv-space colored map, but I could not make the dark blue and dark red using hsv only.

[image]

This is an error map I made and is too bright comparing with other error maps.

What did I forget to make ?

Comment: if you use matplotlib they have different color maps which might suffice for you

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code? Is your data image the same in both cases? Is your color map the same in both case? What is the source of the data? Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).